# Disabling SwipeRefreshLayout resets the layout

Tags: java, android, android-support-library

In a recent update of the android support library disabling the SwipeRefreshLayout also resets the layout whereas it didn't use to before.

```
void reset() {
    mCircleView.clearAnimation();
    mProgress.stop();
    mCircleView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    setColorViewAlpha(MAX_ALPHA);
    // Return the circle to its start position
    if (mScale) {
        setAnimationProgress(0 /* animation complete and view is hidden */);
    } else {
        setTargetOffsetTopAndBottom(mOriginalOffsetTop - mCurrentTargetOffsetTop,
                true /* requires update */);
    }
    mCurrentTargetOffsetTop = mCircleView.getTop();
}

@Override
public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    super.setEnabled(enabled);
    if (!enabled) {
        reset();
    }
}
```

I don't want `reset` being called when I disable the layout, but I can't find a straightforward way of doing it. I thought of extending the `SwipeRefreshLayout` class and overriding `setEnabled` but I can't access the grandparent class' `setEnabled` that way. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place your class to `android.support.v4.widget`, you can do something like this:

```
package android.support.v4.widget;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

/**
 *
 */

public class MySwipeRefreshLayout extends SwipeRefreshLayout {
    private boolean settingEnabled = false;

    public MySwipeRefreshLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MySwipeRefreshLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        try {
            settingEnabled = true;
            super.setEnabled(enabled);
        } finally {
            settingEnabled = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    void reset() {
        if (!settingEnabled) {
            super.reset();
        }
    }
}
```